how to manipulate a Thread with java android studio
I have a for loop where I retrieve texts from my activity and I would like to send them in blocks via Bluetooth, but it groups and sends everything at once.
in Toast it sends the message every second, but when I use connectThread it sends all the blocks at once
   public void btnCarregarMapa(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        final String[] enviaDadosBt = new String[30];
        if(conexaoBt.retornaConexao()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                enviaDadosBt[i] = "{\"function\":\"2\"";
                for (int ii = 0; ii < 23; ii++) {
                    String text = (String) textView[i][ii].getText();
                    text = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(text.replace(",", ".")));
                    enviaDadosBt[i] = enviaDadosBt[i] + ",\"p[" + i + "][" + ii + "]\":\"" + text + "\"";
                }
                enviaDadosBt[i] = enviaDadosBt[i] + "}";
                Toast.makeText(this, enviaDadosBt[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                conexaoBt.ConnectedThread.enviarBt(enviaDadosBt[i]);

            }
        }
    }

ConnectThread Code
public static class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private static InputStream mmInStream = null;

        private static OutputStream mmOutStream = null;
        static String dadosBt;
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
            // member streams are final.
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
            }
            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    dadosBt = new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                    handler.obtainMessage(LEITURA_BT,bytes,-1,dadosBt).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void enviarBt(String enviaDados) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = enviaDados.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

I would like the Thread ENVIARBT to send the message in separate blocks according to the call in the loop

What do you mean by "blocks"?   Sockets are byte stream oriented.  There are no blocks at the socket level.  If you want them, you have to implement them as an "application protocol" over the socket's byte stream.

"how to manipulate a Thread with java android studio" Android Studio is just the IDE. It  has nothing to do with how the application executes.
